# My thread is not working properly in production environment. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread in my java code as given below. It is working fine in local Dev and QC environment. But some data is missing Production environment. Is there any problem in the following thread? Is there any way that i can reproduce the same?

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
private ProcessBean processBean;    

public MyThread(ProcessBean processBean) {

    this.processBean = processBean;
}

public void run() {     
    processCommand();
    try {

        processData(processBean);

    }catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

} 

private void processCommand() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Boolean processData(ProcessBean processBean) throws Exception{ 

    doSomething();
}
}
```

In the following code processData() method will process the data. So some data is not being processed randomly giving no clue.

The calling for the thread is as follows:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool =   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

MyThread myThread = new MyThread(processBean);

scheduledThreadPool.schedule(myThread, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Please help me.

Comment: the above code would not even compile

Comment: @salyh This is a minimum sample...we probably don't want/need more than this.

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint inside the `run()` method of your thread to see if it ever gets hit?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen though the parameters of `processData` and `processCommand` are switched between their usage and their definition. Furthermore, OP might hide the actual problem in one of his simplifications and is thus not solvable by us

Comment: I would speculate that a Throwable object may be getting thrown that does not extend from Exception (such as an Error: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html).  In this case, your thread would stop processing and you would not see any stack trace printed out.  To test this theory, try catching Throwable instead of Exception.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. It is a working copy and working properly in local environment. The Only problem is, some data is not processed in production environment. No data issue, no exceptions. Don't know if it is a concurrency problem.. or something else.. there are multiple calls for this thread in different scenarios with same(high) priority

Comment: @qexyn  will try..